# ES6 - Duplicate declaration on importing files

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

in pre-es6:

```
var stream = require("./models/stream");
var stream = require("./routes/stream");
```

It works fine.

In es6:

```
import stream from './models/stream';
import stream from './routes/stream';
```

Error:

```
TypeError: /var/www/.../es6/app.js: Duplicate declaration "stream"
> 31 | import stream from './routes/stream';
```

Any ideas how can I import it properly?

Comment: Why would you import / require to `steam` twice in the first place?

Comment: This is a legit question. Why it's been down-voted without any comment?

Comment: @FelixKling they are two different files. in pre-es6, `var stream = require("./models/stream");` should be `require("./models/stream");` - i guess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-declaring the `stream` variable and never use it, so you can just import first file without assignment:

```
import './models/stream';
import stream from './routes/stream';
```

Comment: but it has this error `Unexpected token (26:12) > 27 | import from './models/stream';
`

Comment: It should be just: import './models/stream';

Answer (score 3):

Use different module names

```
import stream from './models/stream';
import streamroutes from './routes/stream';
```

Comment: Your second one should be `import {default as streamroutes} from` or just `import streamroutes from`.